# Scoping Neo4j driver and session objects

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, neo4j

I am currently at the beginning of the learning curve with *Neo4j*, so I am making a lot of assumptions about scoping for Dependency Injection (currently experimenting in a Razor Pages application).

Assumption 1: **Driver** is a lightweight protocol wrapper that would be safe in Singleton scope.

Assumption 2: It might be useful to scope **Session** to the web request lifetime. For instance, I might want to add to a transaction in some middle-ware.

Here's some example DI setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddSingleton(_ => GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "hubdb")))
        .AddScoped(_ => _.GetRequiredService<IDriver>().Session())
        .AddRazorPages();
}
```

And a trivial *business* object that will be wired up and injected into a *PageModel* class:

```
public class SignupVendor
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public SignupVendor(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(string name)
    {
        using var transaction = await session.BeginTransactionAsync();

        try
        {
            var result = await transaction.RunAsync(
                "CREATE (v:Vendor {name:$name}) RETURN v", 
                new { name });

            await transaction.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you confirm or comment on my assumptions?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this doc as yet https://neo4j.com/docs/pdf/neo4j-driver-manual-1.7-dotnet.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link, much appreciated, I hadn't managed to track that down yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reference [Neo4j 1.7 Driver Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/pdf/neo4j-driver-manual-1.7-dotnet.pdf)

> Assumption 1: Driver is a lightweight protocol wrapper that would be safe in Singleton scope.

Short Answer: **Yes**

From Docs

> ### The driver object
>
> A Neo4j client application will require a driver instance in order to
> provide access to the database. This driver should be made available
> to all parts of the application that need to interact with Neo4j. **In
> languages where thread safety is an issue, the driver can be
> considered thread-safe.**
>
> #### A note on lifecycle
>
> Applications will typically construct a driver instance on startup and destroy it on exit. Destroying a driver
> instance will immediately shut down any connections previously opened
> via that driver; for drivers that contain a connection pool, the
> entire pool will be shut down.

*emphasis mine.*

---

> Assumption 2: It might be useful to scope Session to the web request lifetime. For instance, I might want to add to a transaction in some middle-ware.

Short Answer: **Yes**

From the Docs

> ### Sessions
>
> A session is a container for a sequence of transactions. Sessions
> borrow connections from a pool as required and so should be considered
> lightweight and disposable. In languages where thread safety is an
> issue, a session should not be considered thread-safe. **In languages
> that support them, sessions are usually scoped within a context block.**
> This ensures that they are properly closed and that any underlying
> connections are released and not leaked.

*emphasis mine*